# How to exclude a list from a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame consisting of 4 columns and 30000 rows. The last column is my target. I needed to exclude a sublist from that based on indices, and make a new dataset. To shed more light on it, I needed to exclude from the main dataset, 100 indices before and 100 indices after the index.  I tried to define a function to do that through a for loop like below:

```py
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
df = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=4)

NEW_middle_index = [1037, 1112, 1187, 1262, 1337, 1412, 1562]

XX , yy = [],[]
def data_reader(df,NEW_middle_index):
  for i in NEW_middle_index:
    
    y = df.iloc[i-100:i+100:,3]
    X = df.iloc[i-100:i+100,:].drop(columns='Target')
    XX.append(X)
    yy.append(y)
  return XX,yy

data_reader(df,NEW_middle_index) #edited here
```

It could do it for `XX` correctly but for `yy`, it is not capable of excluding and it repeats the same number of the first group which is incorrect. Also, I used a dictionary to do that, and again I got the same answer.

Comment: Imports are missing from your code, could you post your input too ? (Just says 10 lines and use i +1 i-1

Comment: I don’t know how iloc works on panda data frame but shouldn’t y go from 0 to I-100 and from I+100 to 30000 ?

Comment: @pippo1980 you're right, it seems weird but I got confused. Also, it should be mentioned that I need `y` from `i-100` to `i+100` which has been done correctly for `X`.

Comment: Ok don’t know how drop works though it was actually deleting x range

Comment: @pippo1980 `drop` is nothing related to the `y` which I dealt with. Imagine if you were, how did you write

Comment: Could you show sample data and the expected result? I think this is possible without iteration, but the task is not clear.

Comment: I was saying that I though that X iloc selection was right because drop() was actually removing the selected range from the data frame and not as you explained keeping just it. That’s why I didn’t realize you wanted to keep the i+-100 range and not thrashing it. As I said I don’t know panda but thanks to you know I know a little bit more

Comment: My only question now is how the selection behaves when i -100 or i +100 exceeds the data frame range

Comment: @pippo1980 I have found and answered my question but am banned to ask any question, if it is possible, upvote to release my ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found My solution to exclude a list from a list using `enumerate` inside of `for-loop`.

The only necessary thing was using enumerate. The code below is the final solution of that.

```
for extra_index, i in enumerate(NEW_middle_index):

      
    y = df1.iloc[(len(new_df)*extra_index)+i-100:(len(new_df)*extra_index)+i+100,2]
    
    X = df1.iloc[i-100:i+100,:].drop(columns='Target')
```

with this method, in every cycle of `for-loop` it opens the file which relates to that cycle in exclude a required list from that file and it closes the file and so on.